How can I scale down the distance between objects without affecting their size?
I got multiple objects parented to an empty and want them to be like scaled down on the Z-Axis but without affecting their actual size, like just the distance between the objects would be scaled down.
How can I do this?

To transform an object’s location directly, enable Affect Only Locations in the Tool Settings Options. Then scale using SZ. In this case I'm using the 3D Cursor Transform Pivot Point so it scales toward the 3D Cursor.

